# Angular JS call to Sinatra not returning data

Tags: javascript, mysql, ruby, angularjs, sinatra

I'm trying to get the partial 'downloads' of Angular js to get information form the MySQL database via JSON from Sinatra. I've written the code below but it's not working, I wonder if my routing in app.rb is wrong, or the controller in Angular.

If anyone could help me work this out that would be fantastic, as I couldn't find any relevant tutorials on this online. Many thanks.

In app.rb

```
get "/#/view1/downloadData" do
 #get list of downloads for user
@download = Download.all(:order => [:downloadID], :limit => 20)

if @download
    @download.to_json
    #log to console if JSON pulled in correctly
    puts "get list of downloads successful"
else
    halt 404
    #log to console if JSON failed
    puts "get list of downloads JSON failed 404 displayed"
end
end
```

In partials/downloads.html

```
<p>Manage downloads</p>
<ul ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
     <li>ID: {{download.title}}, Name: {{download.downloadID}}</li>
</ul>
```

In js/controllers.js

```
//'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('MyCtrl1', [function($scope, $http) {

    //a scope function to load the data.
$scope = function () {
  $http.get('/#/view1/downloadData').success(function(data) {
     $scope.items = data;
     console.log(data);
     console.log("data got succesfully");
  });
};
}])
.controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

}])
.controller('MyCtrl3', [function() {

 }]);
```

Comment: `it's not working` isn't a real error description. Also, it should be fairly straightforward to test if your app.rb works, you already log the result of the call.

Comment: puts returns nil, that may be why your API doesn't return any data. Try inverting your puts and returns in app.rb

Comment: Sorry, not working wasn't very descriptive. Basically it's not returning data and I'm not sure where the fault is.

Comment: Do you mean inverting the if statement?

Comment: I mean inverting the "@download.to_json" and "puts "get list of downloads successful"" lines

Comment: Also you shouldn't use a "#/" route for your sinatra API. Since it starts with "#" it is a fragment which will not leave the angular app. Try to use instead "/view1/downloadData' both in js/controllers.js and in app.rb

Comment: Thanks, after looking through it I think it's a problem with the route, as there are no logs for either the data being pulled successfully or it failing with a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a JavaScript debugger such as Chrome Developer Tool to break down the problems. The code in the question have several different issues and it will be hard to debug without it. By using JS debugger, you can tell if the request was correctly issued, it was issued to the right URL, as well as you can look into the data passed between the client and the sinatra server.

Let's look into all the problems.

First, the syntax for the definition of controller is wrong and debugger would show `TypeError: Cannot set property...` error.  See [Note on Minification of Angular Doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#controller_a-note-on-minification).  You need to change the line into something like this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
```

Second issue is that the line intended to define a scope function is destroying the scope. A scope function requires an identifier:

```
$scope.loadData = function () { ... }
```

and defining a scope function doesn't mean it is called.  You can add a call like as below:

```
$scope.loadData();
```

Third issue is that the `$http.get` call is requesting a url containing `#` character, which indicates a fragment of an URL and it is largely equivalent of requesting `GET /` with parameter. There's no good reason to define a JSON API under `#`.  I would change that to `/view1/downloadData`.  Sinatra app should have correspnding GET handler.

Fourth issue is that the partial code refers `$scope.download`, but `$http.get`'s `success` handler is setting `$scope.items`.

Lastly, based on the Sinatra code, it is returning a JSON array.  The rendering code needs to use `ng-repeat` to render all the items.

JS code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    // a scope function to load the data
    $scope.loadData = function() {
        $http.get('/view1/downloadData').success(function(data) {
            $scope.items = data;
        });
    }
    $scope.loadData();
}]);
```

HTML code

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">ID: {{item.title}}, Name: {{item.downloadID}}</li>
</ul>
```

Simplified Sinatra code

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

get '/view1/downloadData' do
  # I'm guessing the database is returning something like this:
  [{'title' => 'title 1', 'downloadID' => 'ID 1'},
   {'title' => 'title 2', 'downloadID' => 'ID 2'}
  ].to_json
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer, I will work on this now and get back to you.

Comment: I've just implemented the changes, but now the partials aren't linking up and displaying on the index page? I assume this is an issue with the route provider in app.js or the controller?

Comment: You can see if $scope.items is getting the data by setting a breakpoint or putting a `console.log()` statement.  If `$scope.items` is correctly filled, then that's rendering issue.  Otherwise, see if the data is coming back from the server.

Comment: I think I just have in issue with the data coming back from the server.. The JSON you provided works fine, but when it's pulling it in from my db it's bringing in an empty array :/